# How can I use a Listbox Control to Correctly Handle Entry of a New Record?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a listbox on my form which gives me an error.

The `ProductNo` field is the primary key.

This error happens when I partially enter a new record and decide to navigate away from the `ProductNo` control to the listbox item.

Bellow is my current nightmare:

```
Private Sub InventoryListBox_AfterUpdate()

    ' Find Record that matches the control.
    Dim rst As Object
    Set rst = Me.Recordset.Clone

    rst.FindFirst "[ProductNo] = '" & Me![ListBox] & "'"
    If Not rst.EOF Then
        Me.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark    'Error here!
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Test the `NoMatch` property instead of the `EOF` property, e.g.:

```
Private Sub InventoryListBox_AfterUpdate()
    Dim rst As Recordset
    Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone

    rst.FindFirst "[ProductNo] = '" & Me![ListBox] & "'"
    If Not rst.NoMatch Then
        Me.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark
    End If
End Sub
```

The above assumes that `ProductNo` is a string-valued field.

Comment: Many thanks but No luck. Is there a way of abandoning the new record entry completely? Currently I have to operate the Esc button.

Comment: How about using the Before_Update event instead? With Cancel = True and Me.Undo you can cancel your entry.